# getch returns 2 characters when I type one

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, console-application

When I use getch, it always appends the caracter read with a null character.

When I use the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char c = 0;

    while (c != 'x')
    {
        c = _getch();
        printf("Char read: <%c> \n", c);
    }
}
```

It returns the follwing on the console, when I press the keys "asdx":

```
Char read: <a>
Char read: < >
Char read: <s>
Char read: < >
Char read: <d>
Char read: < >
Char read: <x>
```

This is  compiled in VS 2017 in a plain new single file project, running on a windows 10 console window. I tried removing the _UNICODE and UNICODE define.

Comment: How do you know it's a null character?  BTW `_getch()` returns `int`.

Comment: works as expected for me, have you tried printing the numerical value of c to see what it is?

Comment: I know it's a null because I traced it into the debugger. I tried with either int or char, I got the same result.

Comment: If I understand your issue, From the code what I understand is the second character is the NEW LINE FEED \n.

Comment: I type "asdx", no return between the letters.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the issue.

Comment: This is apparently a problem in some versions of Windows SDK, see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/247770/-getch-broken-in-vs-157.html

Comment: @AlanBirtles: it works for me in Debug mode but fails in Release mode. Same behavior as OP.

Answer (score 4):

Well, crap!

It's a (rather new) bug in windows.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/247770/-getch-broken-in-vs-157.html

> "When building a console application using the _getch() function
>   suddenly returns two times for each keypress"

got the following response from microsoft:

> " Thanks for reporting this! This will be fixed on a future windows
>   update."

UPDATE:
As stated in the link above, setting the runtime to **statically link** with a **previous version of the C runtime** will fix the issue, but you need to make sure all your related projects (if you are building a library, for example) also use the same runtime. (I tested it)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to (or you can't) use a previous version of the Universal C Runtime, you can use `_getwch` instead of `_getch`, as the problem doesn't affect to `_getwch` function.

Note that `_getwch` can return Unicode characters, so it may return distinct values than `_getch` for some keys. For example, for `€` character, `_getch` returns 0x3f (`?`) while `_getwch` returns 0x20ac (Unicode value for €)