# Why are there two characters while I press just once?

Tags: c

Why do I get two iterations while I press just one alphabet key (for example, `a`)?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char c;
    do
    {
        c = getch();
        printf("Your input: %c\nPress x to exit.\n\n", c);
    } while (c != 'x');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Count again. how many keys did you hit on your keyboard?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I think I press just once!

Comment: Really ? You didn't slap `Enter` afterward ?

Comment: `getch()` is not part of the C standard library; use `getchar()` instead;  that won't change the behavior of your program, but future you will be very grateful to present-day you;  and, the comments and answers about also pressing `[ENTER]` will make sense

Comment: @WhozCraig The whole reason to use `getch` in your brand new MS DOS program is to skip enter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getch returns 2 characters when I type one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792349/getch-returns-2-characters-when-i-type-one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known bug in the Windows VS 15.7 `_getch` implementation, reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/247770/-getch-broken-in-vs-157.html).

I can reproduce your problem with your code, pressing just a single key.

Comment: I kept the original question with `getch()` rather than `_getch()` even though both behave almost the same with my naked eyes.

Comment: Why do I need to include `conio.h`? The current code snippet suffices to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Just because not defined functions are assumed to return `int` in C (not allowed since C99). Furthermore, `main` return type should be `int` too, as `void` is not allowed by the standard. Your compiler is having mercy on you.

Answer (score 3):

The `getch` function read *any* character, including whitespace characters such as a newline.

If you pressed the Enter key, `getch` will capture it.

Comment: Some recent Windows versions have a bugged version of `_getch`. I can reprocude the problem without pressing any `ENTER` key.