# ARROWS DETECTION IN C++

Tags: c++, conio

I tried to make a simple program to detect the arrows (up, down, right, and left) like shown in my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#define up 72
#define down 80
#define right 77
#define left 75

using namespace std;
 

int main(){
    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i){
        n = getch();
        if (n == 72) cout << "UP\n";
        else if (n == 80) cout << "DOWN\n";
        else if (n == 77) cout << "RIGHT\n";
        else if (n == 75) cout << "LEFT\n"; 
        else cout << "NO\n";    
    }

            
return 0;
}
```

So it is supposed that the loop will iterate 4 times but it actually iterates 2 times and this what is given to me when I press the up key 2 times :

[image: The Output]

So what should I do and thanks in advance

Comment: The output looks like it accepted 4 characters. Are you pressing any other keys in between the up key?

Comment: Can you modify the last output instruction to output `n`? `else cout << "NO " << n << "\n";` What happens if you do that?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Also, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792349/getch-returns-2-characters-when-i-type-one It may be a Windows bug I guess. Does it also happen with non-arrow keys? For instance what happens if you press a letter key?

Comment: @damix911 it's quite possible that the arrow keys generate a two character sequence, even if there's no Windows bug.

Comment: It is clearly stated in Microsoft's documentation for [`_getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=vs-2019) that arrow keys and function keys return two codes. These should be a `0xE0` (indicating an extended character) value followed by the key scan code.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm and just for completeness it should be noted that 0xE0 will be either 224 or -32 in decimal.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, 1201ProgramAlarm. Thank you, I kinda remembered something about the arrow being an extend character from my old console programming days, but when I looked it up in Google it suggested that it could be a bug. But to me it totally make sense that there is something different about the arrow keys. That is why I asked [what happens when the user presses a letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853878/arrows-detection-in-c#comment112915325_63853878).

Comment: It looks like the OP of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792349/getch-returns-2-characters-when-i-type-one) was having a similar problem even with no arrows involved.